# Cant use a closure as event listener to pushState

Tags: javascript, closures, pushstate

I want to use a closure as an eventlistener (im working on a routing library), so i created a class that does exactly that

```
'use strict';
var RouteManager = RouteManager || {};

RouteManager.OnClickDelegate = function(UrlHandler)
{
    var handler = UrlHandler;

    return function delegate(e)
    {
        e = e ||  window.event;
        var element = e.target || e.srcElement;
        if (element.tagName == 'A') {
            console.log("link click");
            window.history.pushState({},"",e.href);
            //this.handler.handle(element.href);
            return false;
        }
    };
};
```

assignment:

```
document.onclick = RouteManager.OnClickDelegate(new UrlHandler());
```

However, although assigning the closure as an event listener works ("link click" is logged correctly) the state isnt pushed

to make matters even stranger, this works correctly:

```
document.onclick = (function(UrlHandler){
    var uh = UrlHandler;
    return function delegate(e)
    {
        e = e ||  window.event;
        var element = e.target || e.srcElement;
        if (element.tagName == 'A') {
            console.log("link click");
            window.history.pushState({},"",e.href);
            //this.handler.handle(element.href);
            return false;
        }
    };
})(new UrlHandler());
```

Any ideas?

Also, please dont suggest a working routing library, its not what im asking for

Comment: Why the closure? You're not using the `UrlHandler`/`handler`/`uh` in there at all.

Comment: Very unlikely that one works but the other doesn't. Notice however that you probably want to use `element.href` instead of `e.href`.

Comment: yeah, i noticed a couple hours ago, the thing is working now. I feel very stupid to say the least. Put it as an answer so i mark it as answered.

Answer (score 0):

> the state isnt pushed

Probably because `e.href` is `undefined`. You want `element.href`.

---

Notice that in your closure you can use the parameter variable directly, you don't need that local variable declaration. Just use this:

```
RouteManager.OnClickDelegate = function(handler) {
    return function delegate(e) {
        e = e ||  window.event;
        var element = e.target || e.srcElement;
        if (element.tagName == 'A') {
            console.log("link click");
            window.history.pushState({}, "", element.href);
            handler.handle(element.href);
            return false;
        }
    };
};
```